# Is <children> tag useful in fxml? Should it be removed?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml

IntelliJ checkstyle indicates that this tag should be removed, as it is not required, as in instead of

```
<VBox>
  <children>
    <HBox>
        ...
    </HBox>
    <HBox>
        ...
    </HBox>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

you can simply have

```
<VBox>
  <HBox>
    ...
  </HBox>
  <HBox>
    ...
  </HBox>
</VBox>
```

This indeed helps not having bloated code at some times, but I failed to find a good reference on a convention here.

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) mentions that the  tag is optional as "the loader will automatically add the sub-elements of the VBox to the container's "children" collection". But that doesn't make it very clear if **it would be ok to adopt removing this tag from code or not as a convention?**

Also, Scene Builder seems to add these tags to newly created controls, but it doesn't mind if you remove them. It does not re-add them while editing such a modified file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@DefaultProperty`
a property to which child elements will be added or set when an explicit property is not given. see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/DefaultProperty.html)

`Pane` class and all it's subclasses have `@DefaultProperty` as **children** see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) , so

> Is **children** tag useful in fxml?

i think no , not really

> Should it be removed?

it's depend on your preference

Comment: I don't understand how the discussion of @DefaultProperty and Pane are relevant to the question being asked. Can someone elaborate?